# Control Flow Graph generator for code in C++

Tags: c++, control-flow-graph

I'm looking for Control Flow Graph generator for source code written in C++. 
Do you know any open-source, static generator?

I would like to use it in my graduation project to generate control flow graph and highlight paths which has been executed during the execution of analyzed application.

I've already written entire engine to log executed lines.

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: These kind of questions are explicitly _off-topic_ here. Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic on stackoverflow, but you can probably ask your question on [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Not open source, but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41497191/120163

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`clang`](https://clang.llvm.org/) or [`llvm`](https://llvm.org/).

First compile your program to llvm ir

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -S prog.cpp -o prog.ll
```

Then use [`opt`](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) to generate the control flow graph.

```
opt --dot-cfg prog.ll
```

This outputs a dot file which can be viewed with [graphviz](https://github.com/rakhimov/cppdep/wiki/How-to-view-or-work-with-Graphviz-Dot-files). On a mac you can do `brew install graphviz` and run the following to generate a png.

```
dot -Tpng cfg.main.dot -o main.png
```

You should have one dot file for every function in your program so it may be easier to write a script to automatically convert them all to pngs

Answer (score 0):

CoFlo is a Free and Open Source source code analysis tool which generates and analyzes control flow graphs from C and C++ source.